# CCNet Unzip File

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant

I need to unzip files from a zip file before taking the installation using install shield. What script should I use for unzipping a zip file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could download the 7zip standalone distribution and upload it to your build server. Then call it via the exec node.

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sevenzip/7za920.zip

Answer (score 0):

http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc1/help/tasks/unzip.html

Example copied from Nant doc:

Extracts all the file from the zip, preserving the directory structure.

```
<unzip zipfile="backup.zip"/>
```